# How to format a teaching statement?

Tags: formatting, teaching-statement

I have already written a teaching statement for a faculty position as assistant professor.

I have three questions:

1. What is the right tense of teaching statement? (present tense or future)
2. Must I sign the statement of teaching like "best regards" etc? How should I put my name in statement of teaching? I mean is there any template for that?
3. In the last paragraph I put some words on the position that I am applying for, about the university and etc, is that Okay to keep this paragraph?

Comment: it is not clear whether you want to highlight your previous Teaching experience or to highlight your future teaching interests?

Comment: This is too short for an answer, but 1) No "right" tense 2) No 3) Yes

Comment: Actually, I did not mention my previous teaching experiences. Should I write past teaching experiences? How many pages is normal for a teaching statement?

Comment: I used present time verbs in my current teaching statement.

Comment: @user40491: As to length, see https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28594/what-is-the-appropriate-length-and-specificity-for-a-teaching-statement?rq=1  In general, you may find a lot of your questions answered if you browse the [tag:teaching-statement] tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In writing research and teaching statements, I generally use past tense for activities that have been completed, and present tense for ongoing activities—the same way you would in standard "ordinary writing."

Statements such as these do not need to be signed, as they are not letters. (Your cover letter for the whole application is a reinforcement of this.)

As for talking about the position, it certainly seems like a good idea to me to talk about how your experience and teaching philosophy fits the specific position in the application, doesn't it?